# React useStyle for Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Material-UI offers a nice way to style its components for React. where you define the style in a different place then the component. For everybody who has never heard of this this looks like this

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    background: 'linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)',
    border: 0,
    borderRadius: 3,
    boxShadow: '0 3px 5px 2px rgba(255, 105, 135, .3)',
    color: 'white',
    height: 48,
    padding: '0 30px',
  },
});

export default function Hook() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return <Button className={classes.root}>Hook</Button>;
}
```

Here you define the `root` object as the style for the `button` and pass it as a single parameter. This looks so clean and makes the code so much more readable because it separates ui and logic, which gets mixed quiet a lot in compose in my mind.

Is there any way or workaround to have a similar behaviour in Jetpack compose with Kotlin. I thought of a data class that can be destructured or a wrapper function around each object that passes the styling.

Comment: You can use Modifiers and pass them to the Composable, For text styles and other stuff you probably have to write your wrapper class to have it as a single parameter. You could also hold data in a functional interface parameters and if needed you execute the function.

To be more precise there are no lib functions supporting this, you have to write a wrapper for the Composable you want to use

Comment: It is Modifier.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In Compose you can't create styles like this, instead you can create composables with applied styling, and then reuse it in your app. I applied some of your example styles so you should get the idea:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun RootButton(
    onClick: () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    enabled: Boolean = true,
    content: @Composable RowScope.() -> Unit
) {
    Surface(
        contentColor = Color.White.copy(alpha = 1f),
        onClick = onClick,
        enabled = enabled,
        role = Role.Button,
        interactionSource = MutableInteractionSource(),
        indication = rememberRipple(),
        color = Color.Transparent,
        modifier = modifier
            .background(
                brush = Brush.linearGradient(
                    colors = listOf(
                        Color.Red,
                        Color.Yellow
                    )
                ),
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(3.dp),
            )
    ) {
            ProvideTextStyle(
                value = MaterialTheme.typography.button
            ) {
                Row(
                    Modifier
                        .defaultMinSize(
                            minWidth = ButtonDefaults.MinWidth,
                            minHeight = ButtonDefaults.MinHeight
                        )
                        .padding(ButtonDefaults.ContentPadding),
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                    content = content
                )
            }
    }
}
```

Then anywhere in your app:

```kotlin
RootButton(onClick = {}) {
    Text("Hello")
}
```